# Passing column names dynamically to UNPIVOT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, unpivot

I have a table with following data

```
First         Second        Third         Fourth        Fifth         Sixth
2013-08-20    2013-08-21    2013-08-22    2013-08-23    2013-08-24    2013-08-25
```

And using `UNPIVOT`

```
SELECT Data
    ,DATENAME(DW, Data) AS DayName
FROM Cal
UNPIVOT(Data FOR D IN (
            First,
            Second,
            Third,
            Fourth,
            Fifth,
            Sixth  )) AS unpvt
```

I get the following result

```
Data        DayName
2013-08-20  Tuesday
2013-08-21  Wednesday
2013-08-22  Thursday
2013-08-23  Friday
2013-08-24  Saturday
2013-08-25  Sunday
```

Now my question is can we pass column names dynamically to the `UNPIVOT` so that when the columns in the table increases we may not have to alter the statement.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are going to have an unknown number of columns that you will need to unpivot, then you will have to look at implementing dynamic SQL.

You can use [`sys.columns`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to get the names of all of the columns in your `cal` table. If you use the following query you will get the list of all of the columns in your table:

```
select C.name
from sys.columns c
where c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.cal')
```

Now you can use this query along with `FOR XML PATH` to create a comma-separated list of the names to be concatenated to a string to be executed:

```
select @colsUnpivot 
  = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
           FROM sys.columns c
           WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.cal') 
           for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Finally, you will take this list and place it into your query string to be executed so the full query will look like:

```
DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsUnpivot 
  = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
           FROM sys.columns c
           WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.cal') 
           for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

set @query 
  = 'select data, datename(dw, data) dayname
     from cal
     unpivot
     (
        data
        for d in ('+ @colsunpivot +')
     ) u'

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/202c1/7)